# How to append SVGs to a <div>?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, svg

Though there are many answers on SO on how to append an SVG in a div but i couldn't get any of them to work for me. May be because i've never worked with SVGs before.

So, i'm creating an SVG on my node server and then creating a JSON object with some other data along with SVG in it

```
svgFiles.push({
   'file': svgDump, //This holds well created SVG
   'vp': JSON.stringify(viewport),
   'page': pageNum
});
```

and then sending it back as a response to my angularjs code.

```
$http({ ... }).then(function callback(resp) { // request to node server
  var svg = resp.data.file;
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  var oldContent = container.innerHTML; // There is going to be an array of objects with SVG data hence i need the 'APPEND' functionality
  // But currently assuming there is only 1 object for demo purpose
  container.innerHTML = oldContent + svg;
})
```

Now that i've my SVGs saved in a variable, i expected that appending it in any DIV should work.

Though it did work but it was all plain text including stuff like @font-face, src etc.

I'm sure there is something that i'm missing or not doing the right way. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this with help of a friend. 

All i needed to do was:

```
$http({ ... }).then(function callback(resp) { // request to node server
  var svg = resp.data.file;
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(svg, "image/svg+xml");
  container.appendChild(doc.documentElement);
});
```

Comment: Using DOMParser has made rendering of SVGs very very slow however when i append SVG (not stored in a string like above) directly in DOM, there is no lag/performance issue as such.